# PJSIP issue in receving the message in background mode

Tags: iphone, sip, pjsip

I have VOIP app having the background modes enabled. I am using PJSIP to connect to SIP server.Application is able to get message in foreground, but facing issue in receiving messages, while it is in background.I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#keepalive)

But I am not sure how can I send keep alive manually at the beginning of background ,as mentioned there.

Any help is appreciated on this issue. Is there any iOS working sample which implements message sending and receiving in background and foreground .

Comment: Did you found the solution??

Comment: @Eesha I got solution for this It is working fine as of now. But it is not a suggested solution for iOS8+. For iOS 8+ we need to use PushKit to bring the app from background to alive.

Comment: Have you done call answering..??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537727/how-to-create-callback-in-ios-that-should-be-called-by-the-library

Comment: Yes I have done call answering with user interaction.

Comment: Ho do you implemented?  I am stuck on this from last 7-8 days :-(