# How to create callBack in iOS that should be called by the library

Tags: ios, callback, pjsip

I am developing a VOIP_App that uses `PJSIP Library` which is written in `C-Language`, most of the methods written in that library are called automatically according to the situation.

There is method named `on_incoming_call` called automatically and call is received by user, I want to add some user interactions for receiving call, I need to create some callBack, that should be called in this method, and the method definition should be written in `Objective-C`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
/* Callback called by the library upon receiving incoming call */
static void on_incoming_call(pjsua_acc_id acc_id, pjsua_call_id call_id,
                         pjsip_rx_data *rdata)
{
    pjsua_call_info ci;

    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(acc_id);
    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(rdata);

    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);



    PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "....\n\n\n Incoming call from %.*s!!  \n\n\n",
          (int)ci.remote_info.slen,
          ci.remote_info.ptr));

    /* Automatically answer incoming calls with 200/OK */
    pjsua_call_answer(call_id, 200, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: The above method itself is the Callback method from the PJSIP library. You need to display the UI from this method. And on user interaction call `pjsua_call_answer` method to Accept the call. `pjsua_call_hangup_all()` to reject the  call.

Comment: I am currently working on a Swift implementation of `pjsip`. The way I handle callbacks is, all callback functions of `pjsua` (`config.cb.`) are assigned to methods of a class, which will then use a `delegate` protocol to notify the rest of the code of the event. You can use `delegates` in Obj-C as well as Swift, depending on which language you use for the rest of the language.

Comment: @cybrox Do you know How to set Current Online Status, how to get online status of our contacts? And Timer Value of Call Duration?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your objective by posting a notification from the callback in the PJSIP library

```
static void on_incoming_call(pjsua_acc_id acc_id, pjsua_call_id call_id,
                     pjsip_rx_data *rdata){
   pjsua_call_info ci;
   NSString *callerNumber = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ci.remote_info.ptr];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:
     @"IncomingCall" object:callerNumber];

pjsua_call_answer(call_id, 200, NULL, NULL); //Comment out this line and instead call this in your UIViewController to accept the call on click of some button or whatever UI action you desire 

}
```

Now you can observe this notification in the AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(launchIncomingVC:) name:@"IncomingCall" object:nil];
}
```

And then this function to show your UIViewController for accepting or rejecting the incoming call

```
-(void)launchIncomingVC:(NSNotification *) notif
{
    NSLog(@"LAUNCH INCOMING CALL VC");

    YourViewController *rvc = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryBoardName" bundle:nil];
    rvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerIdentifier"];

    rvc.paramCallerNumber = noti.object; //pass the caller number to show it on the incoming view

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

            UIViewController *topRootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
            while (topRootViewController.presentedViewController)
            {
                topRootViewController = topRootViewController.presentedViewController;
            }

            [topRootViewController presentViewController:incomingVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        });

}
```